# Laravel Elastic Beanstack here is no existing directory error when deployed

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Laravel site to AWS Elastic Beanstalk through Github and Code Deploy, and I keep errors around permission or directory issues such as:

```
There is no existing directory at "/var/app/staging/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied
```

Now the error is easy to fix, I just have to ssh into the server and run

```
sudo php artisan config:cache
```

But that is not pratical. My file .ebextensions/98-artisan.config contains the following:

```
container_commands: 
  01-no_dev: 
    command: "composer.phar install --optimize-autoloader"
  02_set_directory: 
    command: "cd /var/www/html"
  03_create_env: 
    command: "cp .env.empty .env"
  04_popluate_env: 
    command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r 'to_entries | .[] | \"\\(.key)=\\(.value)\"' > .env"
  05-migrate: 
    command: "sudo php artisan migrate --no-interaction --force"
  10-migrate: 
    command: "sudo php artisan key:generate --no-interaction --force"
  11-migrate: 
    command: "sudo php artisan config:cache"
  12_set_directory: 
    command: "cd /var/app/current/"
  13-migrate: 
    command: "sudo php artisan key:generate --no-interaction --force"
  14-migrate: 
    command: "sudo php artisan config:cache"
```

What am I doing wrong in my deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is running `artisan config:cache` as a container command.

If you do this, Elastic Beanstalk will run the command in the **staging** directory before it moves the file to the **current** directory as part of its deployment process.   This means your storage path is incorrectly cached as staging, as in your error message.

Instead, add it as a post deploy hook shell script in the two locations below:

**/.platform/hooks/postdeploy/cache.sh**

**/.platform/confighooks/postdeploy/cache.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:cache

php artisan view:cache
```

By adding both files, the cache is maintained for both full updates and updates to the environments configuration variables only.